# In gdb, is it possible to find out which memory address has a certain value?

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, gdb, memory-address

For example, I want to find out which memory address(es) stores the value 0xbffff5a0. Can gdb give me a list of address within a certain range that has this value?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes.

GDB provides a macro language facility. You can define a macro function to iterate over an address range, and compare against a provided value. This is not tested, but the macro could look something like this:

```
define findvalue
 set $val=$arg0
 set $p=(char *)$arg1
 set $e=(char *)$arg2
 while ($p < $e)
  if ($val == *(int *)$p)
   print (int *)$p
  end
  set $p=$p+1
 end
end
```